# How do I troubleshoot the cause of Ubuntu unable to locate packages that are on the server?

Tags: apt, package-management

Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop
Trying to install a package from an offline mirror and I get the error:
Unable to locate package scribus.

The debs for the package are on the server.
The package is in the package list.
The same computer can find the package from the official Ubuntu server.

This package is an example. I've run into this with several packages on this mirror.

Things I've tried:
apt clean
apt update
add-apt-repository {main, universe, restricted}
apt update (again)
compared all the hashes - they all match.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more complete details. You should include the mirror and the package name. You should also provide the entire error/output alongside the command or steps needed to reproduce the error.  For the commands you've tried, give the exact command and the entire output of each command. So that we can distinguish it from surrounding text, use code formatting and code fences for blocks. For formatting examples, see: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Apparently Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop defaults to i386 even if it's x64. Specifying **[ arch=amd64 ]** in the sources.list did the trick.